# Layered Architecture using Entity framework where to create the context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, entity

I have n tier architecture I have Data Access, Business Service and UI layer. 
I am using EF 4.0 and MVC. Now question is where to create the context in 1. Business Service and pass the context to Dataacess and return a IQuerable to Data Acess layer.
2. Directly using context in Data Access layer and use Business service just as a proxy( that is basically passing information from DataAcecss and UI).

What is the best place to create 'context'. All the examples available online showing creating context in Data Access Layer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @Robert Harvey and @djacobson.

DAL should handle the context, **with one exception:**

If you're using the **Unit of Work** pattern.

The UoW is a wrapper for the context, so when you "Create a new UoW", you are actually creating a new data context. As a Unit of Work handles *many* repositories, it cannot be instantiated in the DAL itself.

UoW (in the context of MVC) would get passed to the Controllers, which gets passed to the Repository, which is then queried upon.

In this case, you would new up the UoW (and hence the context) during application events (global.asax) begin request, and dispose of at end of request (preferably using a DI container).

Comment: +1 For clear, concise description of UoW pattern. For further info, check out [Martin Fowler's article](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), and MSDN Mag's ["The Unit of Work Pattern & Persistence Ignorance"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx).

Comment: What is the best of doing thing do it as UoW or create the context in Data access

Comment: @Praneeth - it depends on your DAL. I have very simple generic repositories (e.g `Repository<T>`), with basically nothing but Find, Add, Remove. Therefore i work with multiple repositories regulary, so a unit of work is required. If you have one repository handling all your logic/entities, then UoW is not required. It's a matter of opinion, and your adherence to DDD.

Answer (score 1):

As @Robert Harvey states, the examples have the right idea. The EF `Context` is specific to your persistence mechanism (SQL Server database, for example), and therefore belongs in the Data Access layer.

The point of such layering is to make your persistence mechanism invisible to the layers above it, such that you could, for example, change database providers without altering your business / UI code.

Comment: Is there any wrong in creating context in Service layer and passing the object of context to DataAcess Layer and do the actual DB work there.